# How do I determine if location of my gesture recognizer is inside any view?

Tags: ios, swift

I simply have a wrapper UIView with following image views as subviews: `A, B, C`:

[image]

This is how I simply define tap fo my UIView:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer()
wrapper.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
tapGesture.rx.event.bind(onNext: { [weak self] recognizer in
    let subviews = self?.wrapper.subviews.filter { $0.tag == 231 } ?? []
    print("location: \(recognizer.location(in: self?.wrapper))")
    //how do I find here in what subviews my tap is located inside? Example, if I tap in area of 3, then `A, B, C`, if area of 2 then `B, C`...
}).disposed(by: bag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if the frames of A, B, and/or C `contains` the point of the touch in `wrapperView`:

```
let locationInWrapper = recognizer.location(in: self?.wrapper)
if viewA.frame.contains(locationInWrapper) {
    // A is tapped
}
if viewB.frame.contains(locationInWrapper) {
    // B is tapped
}
if viewC.frame.contains(locationInWrapper) {
    // C is tapped
}
```

Using the same approach, you can `filter` the `subviews` rather than using 3 if statements:

```
let tappedViews = subviews.filter { $0.frame.contains(locationInWrapper) }
```

Comment: Could you look also for similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63898888/2725435)?